# Primefaces: How to scroll content in a tabView using p:sticky

Tags: css, primefaces, jsf-2.2

When a user scrolls down I would like to keep my tabView at the top of the view and scroll the content within the tab. I was hoping to achieve this with p:sticky but, instead, the body appears to scroll in back of the tab content, not the tab content. I've tried putting the content inside a scrollPanel but  that needs a height. I've tried some other css solutions but none have worked.

This is a very abbreviated example. Note that the tab content does not scroll. Thanks for any solutions.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</h:head>
<h:body style="width: 1430px;padding:0">
    <p:panelGrid style="height: 100px">
        <p:outputLabel value="header info"/>
    </p:panelGrid>

    <p:tabView id="tabViewId">
        <p:tab id="tab1Id" title="Tab1">
            <h:form>
                <!--    <p:scrollPanel mode="native" style="height: 500px;">-->
                <p:panelGrid style="height: 1000px">
                    <p:outputLabel value="here i am"/>
                </p:panelGrid>
                <p:outputLabel value="scroll to me"/>
                <!--    </p:scrollPanel>-->
            </h:form>
        </p:tab>

    </p:tabView>

    <p:sticky target="tabViewId"/>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which version of Primefaces are you using?

Comment: Primefaces version is 6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoping to understand all your requirements, here's my suggestion.

***Basic idea***: adding sticky position style to Prime Faces tab view header (added some border to understand the behavior)

```
<h:body style="width: 99%;padding:0">

    <style type="text/css">
        .ui-tabs-nav.ui-widget-header {
            position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
            position: sticky;
            top: 10px;
            border: 1px solid green;
        }
    </style>

    <p:panelGrid style="height: 100px; border: 2px solid; width: 99%">
        <p:outputLabel value="Header info" />
    </p:panelGrid>

    <p:tabView id="tabViewId"
        style="width: calc(99% - 4px); border: 2px solid red;">
        <p:tab id="tab1Id" title="Tab1">
            <h:form>
                <p:panelGrid style="height: 1000px">
                    <p:outputLabel value="here i am" />
                </p:panelGrid>
                <p:outputLabel value="scroll to me" />
            </h:form>
        </p:tab>

    </p:tabView>
</h:body>
```

Check also [this](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky), for browser compatibility of the solution.

Comment: This works for my example. I'll see if it works for my application. Thanks!

Comment: yep, this works for the example and it works in my application as well. Only problem is when I switch to a different tab the content remains scrolled at the position of the previous tab. I can fix that. Pretty simple solution when you know what you are doing. Really appreciate your help, thanks again.